# Referencing specific Range of table's .DataBodyRange

Tags: vba, excel, excel-tables

Let's say I have the following exemplary table

[image]

I have a for loop that runs through the entire `ListColumn(2)` (column C / 3) and ranks the "users" based on who has the most apples (eg. Michael would be 1, Robert 2, etc.)

**However let's say, I want to reference only specific Range of the table

(eg. let's say the `Range("C7:C9") <=> ListRows(3,4,5)`)

How can I do that?**

I have the following code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim my_range As Range

    For Each my_range In tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange 
    ' ^ this runs through entire column instead of the specified range I want!
        my_range.Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Rank(my_range, tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
         ' ^ again, isntead of entire DataBodyRange we should be rather referencing the specific Range
    Next my_range
End Sub
```

Basically, I need to somehow limit the `.DataBodyRange` itself into a specific range, problem is, `.DataBodyRange` is specified to either take entire Column/Row or only 1 Cell  from the entire ListObject as `.DataBodyRange([row index], [column index])`.

So, in the presumed example of selecting Robert,Michael,Laurel `ListRows(3, 4, 5)` the Expected Result would be:

[image]

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to the game, but for posterity...

Use `.Offset` and `.Resize` methods to do just about anything in the `tbl.Range` or `tbl.DataBodyRange` ...

To iterate only select rows:

```
...
Set my_range1 = tbl.Listcolumns(2).DataBodyRange
For LoopControl = StartRow To EndRow
    my_range1.Resize(1).Offset(LoopControl - 1).Value2 = 'your code here
    'Alternate code
    tbl.ListRows(LoopControl).Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2).Value2 = 'your code here
    'Or even:
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Resize(1, 1).Offset(2, LoopControl).Value2 = 'your code here
Next LoopControl
```

Note that you can use `.ListColumns("Apples")` in case the columns are rearranged after the fact. Also, you can `.Offset(, tbl.ListColumns("Apples").Index)` to adapt to changing table structure.

Or to refer to a subset of rows as a single range:

```
Set my_range = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Offset(StartRow - 1).Resize(EndRow - StartRow + 1)
'Alternately:
Set my_Range = tbl.ListColumns(2).Range.Offset(StartRow).Resize(EndRow - StartRow + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference consecutive cells in a column using something like:

```
With tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    For Each my_range in Range(.Cells(3), .Cells(5))
      ' Code here.
    Next my_range
End With
```

Is that what you mean?